# GIT Rebase operation was interrupted by a PC crash. Now repository is unavailable

Tags: git, windows-7, git-extensions

I have 2 branches in my repository. There were no uncommitted changes in any of them.

I pulled the branch1, checked out branch2, and started a branch2 rebase on branch1.
In the middle of the work my PC crashed.

After it finally booted up, i open GitExtensions to find that my repository is totally empty, i see the flashing `'rebase under way'` or something like that, i click it and it pops me the window where i have to chose to fix conflicts, which did not supposed to happen. If i click 'solve' it opens the window where conflicting files should be shown and of course there is none.

I tried to click `abort rebase` but it said that folder is `not a git repository or any of the parents`.

Since then i can do NOTHING. I can't abort, can't see commits. Opening git bash just tells me `/some/path/to repo/repo name ((...) | REBASE )`

when i write `git status` it says its not a repository.

Well i wouldn't care that much about failed rebase BUT, i noticed that all of my source files turned to binary files and that means, my **unpushed** commits are LOST, unless you guys can help me recover it.

I wanted to rebase the branch and push it.... this is frustrating.

EDIT 1:

`.git` directory is in the repository directory (`/some/path/to_repo/repo_name/.git`) as it should be.
The PC crashed at the point when branch2 commits were being reapplied. It means that branch1 commits were already applied to the branch2, the only thing left, was to finish applying branch2 commits. And it crashed after like 10 or 20 commits were applied.

I have now compared the .git direcotries of a cloned repo and the one which crashed.

Cloned repo had these folders:
hooks
info
logs
objects
refs
And these files:
config
description
HEAD
index
packed-refs

The crashed one has an extra folder named `rebase-apply`, also extra files:
COMMIT_EDITMSG
FETCH_HEAD
ORIG_HEAD

Everything else seems to match. I didnt go into folders deeper. And didn't try to compare file contents.

Comment: Where's the .git directory? What's inside? The repo should not be corrupted unless git was interrupted in the middle of writing to the repo (which doesn't happen often).

Comment: I have added extra information as an Edit, please check it out and tell me if i need to provide more.

Comment: Generally git says that if `HEAD` does not exist.  In the middle of a rebase `HEAD` will contain a raw SHA-1, perhaps it contains a corrupted one, or none at all?  In which case putting a valid `HEAD` in place may get you to whatever the next step is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After checking `.git` directory files, i have noticed that ORIG_HEAD and HEAD files contained only NULLS. It seems i have finally figured out how to fix this.

1. Deleted `index` file.
2. Deleted `ORIG_HEAD` file.
3. Deleted `HEAD` file.
4. Made a copy of `FETCH_HEAD` (it was pointing to a Branch1)
5. Renamed the copy to `HEAD`
6. Opened `GIT Bash`
7. Navigated to repository directory.
8. Ran `git status` to check if it sees that the directory is a repository. (It did)
9. Ran `git reset` command.
10. Ran `git rebase --abort` command.

At this point, all the binary source files were text files. Also `index` file got recreated.

When i opened repository through GitExtensions, everything seemed to be back to normal, before the rebase. I tried the rebase once more, but it stopped at one of the commits with an error of
`error: unable to unpack d447b241eba771f175cb2150eec77ec605a86486 header
error: inflateEnd: stream consistency error (no message)
fatal: d447b241eba771f175cb2150eec77ec605a86486 is not a valid object`

11. I cloned the repository (from the local GIT server) to another folder.
12. Copied the source files from recovered repository to the newly cloned one.
13. Checked that it showed me all the changes i have made are correct and no commits are lost.
14. Committed all changes as 1 commit (oh well).
15. Pushed.

Thats it. Now it is working once again. Seems that i have not done any damage to it.

Comment: This just saved my life.

Comment: My comment is same as Brian! Ufff There's no enough +1 for this answer

Comment: Dude you just saved my life as well.  I'd give you +50 if I could.